# MongoDB objectID become [object object] in datatables render

Tags: c#, ajax, mongodb, datatables

I'm building web app with mongoDB as database and datatables to process my table.
My problem is, during the render I got [object object] instead of getting the ObjectID from mongodb retrieval.

So in html i have this code :

```
var t = $("#general-table-list").DataTable({
        sAjaxSource: "/AccountCategories/Get",
        "bFilter": false,
        "deferLoading": 0,
        "columnDefs": [
        {
            'targets': 2,
            'searchable': false,
            'orderable': true,
            'className': 'dt-body-center',
            'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<a href="/AccountCategories/Details/' + full.Id.toString() + '" class="btn btn-info"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Edit</a>  ';
            }
        }],
        "select": [
            {
                "style" : "os",
                "selector": "td:first-child"
            }
        ],
        "columns": [
                { "data": null, "orderable": false },
                { "data": "Name", "orderable": false },
                { "data": "Action", "orderable": false }
        ],
        "order": [],
    })

    t.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
        });
    }).draw();
```

How I get the data :

```
public JsonResult Get(DataTableParameters param)
{
    var data = _helper.GetData(param);
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

below are the screenshot :

[image: http://i117.photobucket.com/albums/o56/po_se_for/deep-code_zpslm86n7qi.png]

this is what was rendered on UI :

[image: http://i117.photobucket.com/albums/o56/po_se_for/deep-code-html_zpsyp8dwjgb.png]

How can I fix this ? Appreciate any helps

**==== UPDATE ====**

I managed to fix this by change the Id
from :

```
[BsonId]
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

to :

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Id` is a completely deconstructed _bson object (as seen in your debugger).  It looks like your server is serializing the `Id` in this manner. And it's there in the server that you'll be able to fix this.

Can't say I've ever seen a server serialize an Id like that before (by default anyway). More commonly as done by Mongoose you'll see an Id erroneosuly jsonified as a _bson object rather than a simple 24 character hex string.

Anyway, the solution exists in your mongo interface that's jsoninfyng the results for your API.

Comment: thanks, i managed to fix it already, details added on the post. :)